# Error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'** en python intentando realizar una operación AND

Tags: python, cast

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de los bits en x posiciones de mi código, necesito hacer un cast de str a int y de int a bin porque pretendo que los lea de un archivo de texto más tarde pero me sale un error en la línea 5:
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'**
No entiendo esto porque al final lo que manipulo son bits, adjunto mi código.
Gracias.

```
data = "240"
dataInt = int(data)
dataBin = bin(dataInt)

bit = (dataBin & (1<<6))>>6

print(bit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `bin` produce un string, no un valor binario:

```
dataBin = bin(dataInt)
```

Lo que quieres son los bits de `dataInt`; tienes que operar directamente con esa variable:

```
bit = (dataInt & (1<<6))>>6
```

**Demo**

Este programa obtiene los bits del valor y los imprime desde el más significativo al menos:

```
for i in range(7,-1,-1):
    bit = (dataInt & (1 << i)) >> i
    print(bit, end="")
print()
```

produce:

```
11110000
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias, ya me funciona!

Answer (score -1):

```
data = "240"
dataInt = int(data)
dataBin = int(bin(dataInt)[2:])

bit = (dataBin & (1<<6))>>6

print(bit)
```

El error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'` ya te indica que estás intentando hacer una operación en la que los operandos son de diferente tipo.

`bin(dataInt)` es un string, en concreto este: `0b11110000`. Necesitas prescindir de los dos primeros caracteres y convertir a entero: `int(bin(dataInt)[2:])`

[Documentación sobre <<, >> y &](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

El resultado es:

```
1
```

Comment: Hmm esto es sumamente redundante e innecesario. Estás haciendo dos conversiones (de entero a string y nuevamente a entero) para luego llegar al mismo lugar.

Comment: Ojo que no fui yo quien downvoteé ;)

Comment: En español se dice _votar en contra_ y _votar a favor_. No existe el verbo _downvotar_, ¡por dios!... :D

Comment: Cosas nuevas que veo por aqui